# Add method in binary search tree not working correctly

Tags: python

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left_child = None
        self.right_child = None
        self.parent = None
        self.root = None
class binary:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
    def add(self, data):
        if (self.root == None):
            self.root = Node(data)
        else:
            self._insert(data, self.root)

    def _insert(self, data, curNode):
        if (curNode.data > data):
            if (curNode.left_child == None):
                curNode.left_child = Node(data)

            else:
                self._insert(data, curNode.left_child)
        else:
            if (curNode.right_child == None):
                curNode.right_child = Node(data)
            else:
                self._insert(data, curNode.right_child)
```

So this add method in my binary class appears to be working correctly, but when i try to run tests, it is just flat out wrong. For example:

```
test = BinarySearchTree()
seed(5)
testdata = sample(range(1, 2000), k=300)
for num in testdata:
    test.add(num)
print(len(test))
```

This will return 17. When it should return 300.

Any idea why this is happening? I took a look at my code and everything appears to be working correctly.

Comment: Could you include the code for `Node` and `RecusionCounter`? Also is `BinarySearchtree` the same as `binary`? Your example isn't reproducible as-is.

Comment: Include the complete code. Also, make sure function names and function calls should be correct.

Comment: Random test cases are not reproducible.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Comment: edited to add the methods

Comment: @hello, you might want to add *all* the methods. What you have won't work without the dunder `__len__()`. If you want to see how to do this, my answer gives one example (I would normally cache this information for performance but, given the small size and educational nature of the question, it's probably not necessary).

Answer (score 0):

There's almost certainly something wrong with the code you *haven't* shown, since the following does exactly what you need, outputting a length of 300:

```
import random

class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left_child = None
        self.right_child = None

class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def add(self, data):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = Node(data)
        else:
            self._insert(data, self.root)

    def _insert(self, data, curNode):
        if curNode.data > data)
            if curNode.left_child is None:
                curNode.left_child = Node(data)
            else:
                self._insert(data, curNode.left_child)
        else:
            if curNode.right_child is None:
                curNode.right_child = Node(data)
            else:
                self._insert(data, curNode.right_child)

    def _count(self, curNode):
        if curNode is None: return 0
        return self._count(curNode.left_child) + 1 + self._count(curNode.right_child)

    def __len__(self):
        return self._count(self.root)

test = BinarySearchTree()
seed(5)
for num in sample(range(1, 2000), k=300):
    test.add(num)
print(len(test))
```

---

Even *with* your added code for `Node` in an update, there appears to be no `__len__` method in your tree type, that dunder method is a prerequisite of being able to get the length of the collection.

In addition, it's rather unusual for a *node* to have a root value and, in any case, you never never seem to set `root` or `parent` to anything.

So the steps to get from the code you have to something workable and/or sensible are:

- Name your class properly. You call it `binary` but instantiate `BinarySearchTree`.
- Remove the superfluous `parent` and `root` from the `Node` class, unless you plan on using them.
- Implement the `__len__` dunder method so you can actually *get* the length.
- Try to use `is` when comparing to `None`, that's the preferred way.
- Optional, based on preference: try not to pollute namespaces, it's probably better to `import random` and explicitly name the things you want to call (like `random.seed`) rather than pollute the normal namespace with items from `random`.
- Optional, stylistic issue: there's no requirement that conditional expressions be surrounded by parentheses (as in C-like languages). My opinion is that this detracts from readability for simple conditionals, so I prefer `if x == 0` to `if (x == 0)`.